# How do I modify openmeetings pages?

Tags: java, web, lzx

How do I modify openmeetings pages in the windows system, and replace the corresponding module under the ubuntu system. I used maven to compile flash module, in the generate target folder there is a jar of the flash package,but in the ubuntu system ,built in the server, I can not find the corresponding package, but I am able to find other packages ,eg:web,webserver.

Any advice?